Getting 503 in even when application is properly deployed and running in backend in mule4
The app and domain is deployed successfully in my local anypoint studio system  and i am able to  open console .. When i hit the API from console i am getting 503 errror .
The same api work from anypoint platfrom , and i am able to get 200 success response
INFO  2024-12-21 10:34:19,571 [ArtifactDeployer.start.01] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.logging: 
**********************************************************************
* Started app 'super-movies-sapi'                                    *
* Application plugins:                                               *
*  - Sockets : 1.2.5                                                 *
*  - HTTP : 1.10.3                                                   *
*  - APIKit : 1.11.2                                                 *
* Application libraries:                                             *
*  - supermovies-spec-1.0.0-raml.zip                                 *
*  - basic-auth-securityscheme-1.0.0-raml-fragment.zip               *
*  - rest-connect-library-1.0.2-raml-fragment.zip                    *
**********************************************************************
INFO  2024-12-21 10:34:19,641 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.logging: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Mule is up and kicking (every 5000ms)                                        +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
INFO  2024-12-21 10:34:19,671 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector: Started ServerConnector@4bf72cae{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{127.0.0.1:61813}
INFO  2024-12-21 10:34:19,675 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.logging: 
**********************************************************************
*              - - + DOMAIN + - -               * - - + STATUS + - - *
**********************************************************************
* default                                       * DEPLOYED           *
**********************************************************************

*******************************************************************************************************
*            - - + APPLICATION + - -            *       - - + DOMAIN + - -       * - - + STATUS + - - *
*******************************************************************************************************
* super-movies-sapi                             * default                        * DEPLOYED           *
*******************************************************************************************************

INFO  2024-12-21 10:34:19,750 [[MuleRuntime].uber.03: [super-movies-sapi].uber@org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.source.ExtensionMessageSource.lambda$reallyDoStart$17:488 @5cd88bfe] [processor: ; event: ] org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.source.ExtensionMessageSource: Message source 'listener' on flow 'api-liveness-flow' successfully started
INFO  2024-12-21 10:34:19,750 [[MuleRuntime].uber.07: [super-movies-sapi].uber@org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.source.ExtensionMessageSource.lambda$reallyDoStart$17:488 @109f5ccd] [processor: ; event: ] org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.source.ExtensionMessageSource: Message source 'listener' on flow 'super-movies-sapi-console' successfully started


can someone help , what i am missing here

The log is hard to read because it is confusing the formatting for [so]. Use  [code block] format for logs and code. Also add a [mre] to the question. We don't have enough information  to understand what the API may be doing. Try testing externally, with curl or postman and add the results to the question too (not in comments).

There might be a case where your Anypoint Studio is not connected to Anypoint Platform to establish a connection with API manager for Auto Discovery. So disable the auto-discovery in locally for testing purpose or set up Anypoint Platform credentials in Anypoint Studio to have a proper connection for API Auto Discovery.
For Disabling,

Try to comment on the Auto Discovery XML config from Code and see how it works or not

Or pass the below VM argument in Anypoint Studio
 -Danypoint.platform.gatekeeper=disabled



Note: Disabling is only for testing purposes.
